# Form with selecting user PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, get

I have to following code:

```
 <select class="form-control" name="user">
    <?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY lastname";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          // output data of each row
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            ?><option><?php echo $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["middlename"] . " " . $row["lastname"]; ?></option><?php
          }
      } else {
      }
    ?>
  </select>
```

The method of the form is get. I want that the user id is set in the get and not what now happens, firstname + Middlename + Lastname. So i want not: webpage.php?user=firstname+middlename+lastname but i want webpage.php?user=$id

Comment: give the option a value which contains id e.g. `<option value="' . $row["id"] . '">`

Answer (score 0):

Please take value attribute in option,please try this code.Because you did not pass the userid.
Please enter the right field in value because i dont't know the name of user id field in your table so please change

```html
<select class="form-control" name="user">
    <?php
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY lastname";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
      {
          // output data of each row
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          ?>
          <option value="<?php echo echo $row["id"]; ?>"><?php echo         $row["firstname"] . " " . $row["middlename"] . " " . $row["lastname"]; ?>
          </option>
      <?php
      }
      }
      else {
      }
    ?>
  </select>
```

option>